# Excel to SQL Server data import error: No value given for one or more required parameters

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server

I am trying import data from Excel into a SQL Server database. But when I run it everything was not uploaded and I run it I got this error:

> No value given for one or more required parameters.

Can anyone help? This is my code:

```c#
protected void Button1_Click1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    String strConnection = "Data Source="";Initial Catalog="";Integrated Security=True";
    //file upload path
    string path = FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName;
    //Create connection string to Excel work book
    string excelConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + path + ";Extended Properties=Excel 12.0;Persist Security Info=False";
    //Create Connection to Excel work book
    OleDbConnection excelConnection = new OleDbConnection(excelConnectionString);
    //Create OleDbCommand to fetch data from Excel
    OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("Select [ID],[StudentName],[CLass],[NRIC],[FixedAmount] from [Sheet1$]", excelConnection);
    excelConnection.Open();
    OleDbDataReader dReader;
    dReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    SqlBulkCopy sqlBulk = new SqlBulkCopy(strConnection);
    //Give your Destination table name
    sqlBulk.DestinationTableName = "StudentParticulars";
    sqlBulk.WriteToServer(dReader);
    excelConnection.Close();
}
```

Comment: Your `catch` block is blank. Are you getting any `Exception`? Put a `MessageBox` and check.

Comment: i have edited my code but having some errors

Comment: When I see Button1_Click1 it looks like you're invoking two separate subroutines on one button click.  Is this deliberate?

Comment: Hope you had given values for `Data Source` and `Initial Catalog`

Comment: ya.. i have given. just that i remove it.